# Why can't I see my latest photos when I try to add a picture to facebook?

Tags: photos, facebook, photos.app

I just imported a bunch of photos from my iphone 6 to my mac book and I have migrated to the new Photos app.  When I go into the Photos app, I do see these pictures that have been imported but when I go to another app (like facebook) and try to add a photo to a post, I go into **Media => Photos** and none of the newly uploaded photos are showing up.

I am not sure if this is related to migrating from **IPhoto** to **Photos** on the mac but any suggestion or explanations on what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rebooting, the pictures showed up